# Validation nullreferenceexception trying to implement new custom syntax

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

Attempting to rewrite my custom rules to suggested new 7.2 FluentValidation syntax and am getting the following error:

NullReferenceException at 
ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Internal.PropertyRule, ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Resources.LazyStringSource.GetString(Object context).

Three different attempts to set up the rule shown. First one is the old one that works, second two are my attempt to rewrite but crash with error above.

```
 //works but marked obsolete
 Custom(rpt =>
        {
           return DateLastObservedValidator(rpt)
               ? null
               : new ValidationFailure("DateLastObserved", "invalid date") { ErrorCode = "BadDate" };
       });

//fails with nullreference exception
RuleFor(rpt => rpt)
     .Custom((rpt, context) =>
         {
             if (!DateLastObservedValidator(rpt))
             {
               context.AddFailure(new ValidationFailure("DateLastObserved", error: "invalid date") { ErrorCode = "BadDate" });
             }
         });

//fails with nullreference exception
RuleFor(rpt => rpt)
     .Must(rpt => DateLastObservedValidator(rpt))
     .WithMessage("invalid date")
     .WithErrorCode("BadDate");
```

function DateLastObservedValidator is a private bool declared inside the validator class.

Comment: I don't see the difference here with our [Custom Validation Test](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/ValidationCustomTests.cs). Can you put together a stand-alone project that repros the issue on GitHub?

Comment: found problem in attempting to recreate - NRE was coming in a ValidatorOptions.DisplayNameResolver I had in my main project. The new Custom syntax brought bug out, had not seen it before.